# how to resize an image on "onClick" using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do i resize an image using jquery?

```
<td align="center"><img width="150px" src="{{=URL(r=request, f='download', args=Product.image)}}" AlT="no picture provided"/></td>
```

the images are loaded directly from the database using a forloop and are displayed on the screen.

all i want to achieve is the increase the size of an image when you click on it. something like this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation1_relative
but it shouldn't keep on increasing the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzMmE/). It is simple. The trick to not increase many times is this condition:

```
if (img.width() < 200)
```

Fiddle's code:

```
<!-- Html -->

<img id="mrbean" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-C6KY8tsc8Fw/T-SVFnncxjI/AAAAAAAAANw/FMiNzA8Zecw/s640/mr.bean.jpg" width="50" height="50" />

<input type="button" value="Increase image size" />

// JavaScript
$("input").click(function() {
    var img = $("#mrbean");

    if (img.width() < 200)
    {
        img.animate({width: "200px", height: "200px"}, 1000);
    }
    else 
    {
        img.animate({width: img.attr("width"), height: img.attr("height")}, 1000);
    }
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzMmE/1/) to resize image back to it's original size on second click.

Comment: hey thank you for this, i haven't had a chance to try this yet but will do it as soon as possible..
did have one question.. after you zoom the image or open it, how do we get out of it instead of clicking the back button or the refresh button? basically, can i click on the image again to make it go back to original size?

Comment: @theNoob well I have just updated my post and the fiddle. Now it resizes image back to the original size on second click. It reads the original sizes from the `width` and `height` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple JSFiddle for you: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54Kch/4).

Simply set a click event on the image using jQuery, then modify the height and width directly.

```
$('.myImg').click(function() {
    $(this).height(400);
    $(this).width(400);
    $(this).off(); //removes the handler so that it only resizes once...
})
```

Comment: hey thank you for this, i haven't had a chance to try this yet but will do it as soon as possible..
did have one question.. after you zoom the image or open it, how do we get out of it instead of clicking the back button or the refresh button? basically, can i click on the image again to make it go back to original size?

Comment: Something very simple like this could do: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andRyanMiller/54Kch/5/). Checks to see what the current height is, then toggles based upon that.